# C# value switching value without me touching it

Tags: c#, monodevelop, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a game in Unity using C#. A part of the code, using a boolean, decides if the player is allowed to buy an upgrade for a building or not. If he is, the integer of the building is increased by 1. Next to that, the boolean gets set to false. If he isn't, nothing happens at the moment.

There is a button in game, functionally increasing the week number by 1, allowing the player again to be able to upgrade building (thus setting the boolean true again).

The problem is that after buying the upgrade, the boolean is set to false, and even when I set it back to true again, when I try to upgrade the building, the boolean appears to be false. I also tried to check it with the help of an integer instead of a boolean (using the values 0 and 1), but the problem is still here.

Here is some code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ActivateTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int transtech = 0;
    public int factech = 0;
    public bool facmag = true;
    public bool transmag = true;

    void OnGUI () {GUI.Box(new Rect(0, Screen.height - 120 - 60, 150, 30), "Week: " + week.ToString());
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(0, Screen.height - 120 - 30, 150, 20), "Continue one week"))
    {       
        NextProcess();
    }
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(20, 70, 120, 20), "Koop upgrade") )
    {
            Debug.Log("Facmag: " + facmag);
        if (facmag == true)
            {
        facmag = false;
            }
    }

    void NextProcess()
    {
        Debug.Log("Next process called");
        facmag = true;
        transmag = true;
        Debug.Log("Facmag: " + facmag);
    }
}
```

So, when NextProcess() is called, the Debug Log shows the value being true. But after the first time buying the upgrade, no matter if I pressed the button to execute NextProcess() or not, the value stays false. I'm wondering if I missed something completely or not. No other code in this class uses the booleans, nor do any of the few other classes I've got do. So where lies the problem?

Comment: Nothing immediately jumps out in the code you've provided.  Are you positive nothing else can modify facmag?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, using the find-function I found out the only code using the boolean is the one provided above, and I checked every other class I have to find out it's not being used. I was thinking, perhaps the problem lies in the use of the class in multiple objects? The two objects use two different booleans (facmag and transmag), so it'd safe a lot of double code. Even so, calling ProcessNext() in bóth instances should set everything right, does it not?

Comment: Can you add a watch to the variable and step through the code to see where it switches?

Comment: I don't think that's possible in Unity3D... Would be incredibly usefull though.

Comment: Don't you think the type of class (MonoBehaviour) would have anything to do with it?

Comment: @Joetjah You do have some [facility for debugging](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Debugger.html) As far as multiple objects go, they are unique instances (as is the case for attached scripts).  Classes shouldn't share variable state.

Comment: Wait scratch that, do you have this script on multiple objects?  if so, the gui elements are going to draw over themselves so you're likely clicking the button of 1 object only.

Comment: Ahh, meaning I should put the booleans in a different script and attach that, for example, to the player instead of the buildings. Nice call, makes sense. Thank you! If you like, you can answer the question with that so I can accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Short Answer]**

If your script is attached to more than 1 object only the top most button in **OnGUI()** is modifying **facmag** or calling **NextProcess().**

**[Slight Expansion of my comment above]**

Unity's order of execution for scripts shared between objects is not controllable.  (You can [modify script order **in a single object**](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-ScriptExecution.html) though.)  That means **OnGUI()** will be called N times for the N objects it's attached to, in [random order](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/371502/order-execution-of-the-same-script.html). Only the "top most" GUI element at a particular mouse position will accept mouse input.

Example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class OverlapButton : MonoBehaviour {
    public string id_;
    void OnGUI(){
            if(GUI.Button(new Rect(0,0,50,50),"Touch")){
                    Debug.Log("I'm object " + id_);
            }
    }
}
```

If you attach this script to 50 objects, Unity will draw 50 buttons but only 1 button will respond to a mouse click and you can't control which one.