# C# parameter switching in TextField with multiple scripts

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a game in Unity using C#. As part of the game, I've got a script attached to a few objects. This script contains the `OnGUI()` method. As I found out before in my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161545/c-sharp-value-switching-value-without-me-touching-it/14162634#14162634), the script and thus `OnGUI()` gets called multiple times.

Now I'm trying to insert a `TextField`, enabling the player to enter a value of money he wants to carry with him from the bank (the selected value is given to the player when he presses a button to confirm). But whatever I try to do, the value in the textfield continues to be 0 (starting value).

I'm wondering if there is a way to enable the TextField to be typed in, without it being overwritten by multiple `OnGUI()` functions from the same script attached to multiple objects, back to `0`?

Comment: The Unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a blank object in your Unity Scene, and attach the script to it. Put the contents of the text field into a public variable int, and reference the variable from other scripts. You can use GameObject.Find and GetComponent method of the script to access the variable and write to the variable if necessary.  Also if you want, you can do a PlayerPrefs.SetInt or SetFloat and a GetInt, GetFloat to set and retrieve the values. But that is cumbersome on resources.

Comment: I have a very messy code and I don't have time to clean it all up. That's why I asked for a solution for this. Putting it on an empty object and using variables from a different script eventually solved the problem. Your given answer gave me a push in the right direction. Thanks.